# How do i generate unique 5 digit customer number with hasid

Tags: php, laravel, hashids

Hi i want to generate `unique` five digit `customer number` containing only digits from `0....9`

i'm using this package : https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php

i'm able to generate `id` but it contains `alphabet` like a...z

this how i'm generating

```
   $id = 12;
   $hashids = new Hashids\HashIds('eabangalore');  
   return $id = $hashids->encode(1, $id, 99);    // output QBsLFJw
```

but i want output something like this 22345,46643,...etc

how can i do that ??

Comment: why not use a random number between 10000 and 99999?

Comment: that github link tells you how to use a custom 'alphabet' ... aka the only characters the hashid will use

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually use this package for creating really unique customer number from 100000 to 999999.

I guess something like this would be a better solution:

```
$idWasNotCreated = true;
while ($idWasNotCreated)
    $id = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    if (User::where('customer_number', $id)->first()) {
        $idWasNotCreated = false;
    }
}
```